# Definitions of Holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have seen holomorphic defined two different ways. The first is that a function f is holomorphic at $z$ if the limit $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}$ exists and the second is that it is holomorphic if there exists a complex number $a$ such that $f(z + h)- f(z) - ah = h\psi(h)$, where $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\psi(h) = 0$.

This makes sense intuitively, but can someone rigorously show why this is true?

Comment: These definitions are equivalent for in any normed vector space and characterise *differentiability*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function $\psi$ exists, then$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{ah+h\psi(z)}h=\lim_{h\to0}a+\psi(z)=a.$$

And if the limit$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h$$exists and it is equal to $a$, you define$$\psi(h)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h-a&\text{ if }h\neq a\\0&\text{ if }h=a.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you just define $\psi (\zeta)$ as $\frac {f(z+\zeta)-f(z)-a\zeta} {\zeta}$ for $\zeta \neq z$ and $0$ for $\zeta =z$ you can see easily that the two statements are equivalent.